# how to configure schema-registry with three kafka clusters using helm?

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, confluent-schema-registry

I just install schema-registry using helm,set `replicaCount=3`,and it is obviously that the topic named `_schema` is blocked. The log shows only one schema-registry client can connect to _schema topic,
first:

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

second:
set `replicaCount=3` and set `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="kafka1:9093,kafka2:9093,kafka3:9093"`

```
helm install my-schema-registry bitnami/schema-registry --version 15.0.1
```

it shows fail to create topic due to first pod created _schema and second pod created _Schema failed.

success install schema-registry connecting to three kafka cluster addresses,and run multi replicas schema-registry

Comment: Have you tried using Confluent Operator instead of Bitnami?